# How to create new JKS keystore for the app that already in play store when we miss the JKS file for android application? lost JKS file

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, sha1, jks

I have an application in the play store but we lost the JKS file that was already used for uploading Applications to the play store I need to update the Application to the play store as the same application doesn't want to create as a new application.

Comment: If you were using "app bundle" you have to ask play store customer support to reset your upload key, app signing key should be unchanged and stored by google. If you were still using "APK upload" you're out of luck, you have to use the exact same signing key to update an app. It's not even just the play store policy, this behavior is baked into android system itself.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, you will have to contact support and create a new JKS file. The article describes this quite well. https://medium.com/@doolatunde/recover-jks-file-to-update-app-on-google-play-1252d08bae16